# Removing a random item from a list C#

Tags: c#, list, matching

my first question on here.
I'm trying to make a matching game using buttons and a list. I am representing the images with letters using the list, when a letter is used it should remove that letter from the list decreasing the number of items in the list. However I am getting the error Index out of range. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Rhys

```
 Random random = new Random();

    List<string> icons = new List<string>() 
{ 
    "!", "!", "N", "N", ",", ",", "k", "k",
    "b", "b", "v", "v", "w", "w", "z", "z"
};


    Button[,] btn = new Button[4, 4];
    //Random r = new Random();            // Random variable
    public GameWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {

            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {

                btn[x, y] = new Button();
                btn[x, y].SetBounds(80 * x, 80 * y, 80, 80);
                btn[x, y].FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
                btn[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_Click);
                btn[x, y].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#35014F");
                Controls.Add(btn[x, y]);
                btn[x, y].Font = new Font("Webdings", 50, FontStyle.Regular);
                AssignIconsToButtons(btn[x, y]);




            }
        }

    }


    void AssignIconsToButtons(Button ButtonToAssign)
    {
        foreach (Button control in this.Controls)
        {

            Button iconButton = control as Button;

            if (iconButton != null)
            {


                int randomNumber = random.Next(icons.Count);
                //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(randomNumber));
                iconButton.Text = icons[randomNumber];
                //iconButton.ForeColor = iconButton.BackColor;
                icons.RemoveAt(randomNumber);

            }
```

Comment: On which line is the error happening?

Comment: If `icons` is empty, `icons.Count` will be `0`. `random.Next(0)` will produce `0` as the `randomNumber`. If you try to access the `0th` element of an empty array, you'll get an Index out of bounds exception.

Comment: It doesn't like the iconButton.Text = icons[randomNumber];

Comment: Quick and dirty fix would be to simply check if the collection is not empty and contains at least n items before you try to remove the item at (n-1) position.

But a better fix would be to ensure that you never generate a random number greater than (n-1) of course ;-) as it was explained in one of the comments above which I think could be a good answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this: ([Random.Next(Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
if (iconButton != null && icons.Count > 0)
{
    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, icons.Count);
    //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(randomNumber));
    iconButton.Text = icons[randomNumber];
    //iconButton.ForeColor = iconButton.BackColor;
    icons.RemoveAt(randomNumber)
}
```

Comment: The code is not correct. Note that on `random.Next(min, max)`, the max value is excluded, so the call should be `Next(0, icons.Count)` or even better `Next(icons.Count)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your random number generation should be:

```
int randomNumber = random.Next(icons.Count-1);
```

this is because your array starts at 0 and count tells you the number of objects in the list.

Comment: I have tried that but it comes up another error which says maxValue must be greater than zero.

Comment: I assume that error comes later in the game so check that icons.count is greater than 1 before trying to remove an item.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks NeverHopeless that worked, now I have only four images displaying on my 
boxes instead of 16, the joys of coding, thanks for the help.

```
  if (iconButton != null && icons.Count > 0)
     {


int randomNumber = random.Next(0, icons.Count-1);
//MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(randomNumber));
iconButton.Text = icons[randomNumber];
//iconButton.ForeColor = iconButton.BackColor;
icons.RemoveAt(randomNumber)
  }
```